# Singleton Pattern with {}?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

> I apologize to move it from here as
>   there was some confusion and thanks to
>   Grey for answer this to realized the
>   mistake. The topic has been moved to
>   [Javascript: Behavior of {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612703/how-to-design-an-object-on-singleton-pattern-in-javascript)
>   to discuss further.

Singleton Pattern with '{}'. Here how it is:

```
var A = {
 B : 0
};

// A is an object?
document.write("A is an " + typeof A);
```

Lets try to clone object `A`

```
var objectOfA = new Object(A);
objectOfA.B = 1;

//Such operation is not allowed!
//var objectOfA = new A();

var referenceOfA = A;
referenceOfA.B = -1;

document.write("A.B: " + A.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

The above `referenceOfA.B` holds a reference of object `A`, so changing the value of `referenceOfA.B` surely reflects in `A.B`.

```
document.write("referenceOfA.B: " + referenceOfA.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

If successfully cloned then `objectOfA` should hold value `1`

```
document.write("objectOfA.B: " + objectOfA.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

**Here are the results:**

*A is an object*

*A.B: -1*

*referenceOfA.B: -1*

*objectOfA.B: -1*

Upto here everything is clear but an object should take `instanceof` on it. But here if you try to use `instanceof` with `A` you got an exception.

Why?

Comment: realised I completely misunderstood.

Comment: What is the point of a 'singleton pattern' in a language with global variables? I am asking for real, why not just say `var B=0`?

Comment: Global variables can be controlled with closures. A very powerful feature. Here a great article on the closure concept: http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an exception:

```
alert(A instanceof Object); // true
```

Tested in Chrome, IE8 and Firefox.

Comment: I was tyring `referenceOfA instanceof A`, where the exception was thrown. `referenceOfA instanceof Object` however returns true.