# Javascript: Behavior of {}

Tags: javascript

> I didn't have a understanding on
>   difference between intializing a
>   variable with {} and a named-function
>   with `new` keyword. I mean which
>   practice should I use to give a
>   definition of an object. Which is more
>   appropiate and for which case?
>
> Then I made a little example to test
>   both practices. And 
>   I found a very simple difference.
>   Whenever you intialized an
>   variable with `{}`, that variable is
>   the only reference of this object
>   definition given in `{}`. `{}` itself
>   doesn't have a name so it can't be
>   called to intialized with new. Only a
>   reference is avaliable to get it.
>
> So it seems we can easily implement
>   singleton pattern on objects using {}.
>   What I see you can't have more than
>   one instances with {} not even you can
>   apply clone if you do you will get
>   only a reference of that object.
>
> Am I assuming a correct behavior of
>   {}?

```
var A = {
 B : 0
};

// A is an object?
document.write("A is an " + typeof A);
```

Lets try to clone object `A`

```
var objectOfA = new Object(A);
objectOfA.B = 1;

//Such operation is not allowed!
//var objectOfA = new A();

var referenceOfA = A;
referenceOfA.B = -1;

document.write("A.B: " + A.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

The above `referenceOfA.B` holds a reference of object `A`, so changing the value of `referenceOfA.B` surely reflects in `A.B`.

```
document.write("referenceOfA.B: " + referenceOfA.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

If successfully cloned then `objectOfA` should hold value `1`

```
document.write("objectOfA.B: " + objectOfA.B);
document.write("<br/>");
```

**Here are the results:**

*A is an object*

*A.B: -1*

*referenceOfA.B: -1*

*objectOfA.B: -1*

Comment: Why are you reposting a question for which you already chose an answer? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612631/singleton-pattern-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/04/04/how-to-make-a-singleton/) may be of use, excerpt:

```
CatNames.instance = null; // Will contain the one and only instance of the class

// This function ensures that I always use the same instance of the object
CatNames.getInstance = function() {
        if (CatNames.instance == null) {
                CatNames.instance = new CatNames();
        }
        return CatNames.instance;
}
```

Note: you should not clone singletons.

Answer (score 1):

A is already an object, so `new Object(A)` just returns A. You can prove this by running

```
var c = {};
alert(c === new Object(c));
```

So no cloning is going on.

What are you actually trying to do, and what does the Singleton pattern have to do with this cloning business?

Comment: Then "b = new Object(c)" should create a new instance of c but it didn't and changing c.Aproperty should not effect b.Aproperty but it do.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `c` is an object, not a constructor, so how can there be a "new instance" of it? Are you expecting `new Object(c)` to create a new object using `c`'s constructor? That isn't what the Object constructor does. See the ECMAScript spec 3rd edition (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), section 15.2.2.1 to see exatcly what it does do. The relevant bit here is *"If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return value."*

Answer (score 1):

For cloning objects you will have to do a bit more work. Something like below.

```
var a = {
    val:1, 
    clone : function(){
       return {val: a.val, clone : a.clone}
    }
};
var b = a.clone();
b.val = 2;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Now you can clone an object and change it values. If you want to clone more complex objects, you could write a recursive function for this.

You can use these object literals as either static classes or as objects with key/value pairs.

If you want to use non static classes (sort of), use the following:

```
var MyClass = new function(){}
MyClass.prototype = { 
    val : 1
};
var a = new MyClass();
```

Hope this helps.